# What is the output of this JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript

why the output comes "Not in the face" for both id??

```
 var message = "Spoon!";
    $( "#foo" ).bind( "click", function() {
      console.log( message );
    });
    message = "Not in the face!";
    $( "#bar" ).bind( "click", function() {
      console.log( message );
    });
```

Comment: All you are doing is, setting a new value for the 'message' variable. When the click event fires, the latest value will be displayed. Try setting different variable for "Not in the face!".

Comment: message  is in global scope for the click handler functions.

Answer (score 2):

Because by the time your click handlers are being executed, your (global) `message` has already been redefined to `Not in the face!`.

Both the definition and redefinition of message occur before your first click.